# Decrease text stroke to make it really thin

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

How do i use offset path to decrease the text thickness? I tried using the negative measurement but it still didn't work.

Comment: Put a stroke using the color of the background.

Answer (score 2):

Add an offset effect in the Appearance Panel. Negative values do work, however it will probably have to be a very low value for a small 12pt font, as shown in the example where I set the offset to -0.05mm

[image]